# jekyll/liquid - how to pass variable as an argument to post.title contains statement?

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I'm trying to filter results of the loop based on hashtags included in titles. If done manually it works perfectly:

```
<article class="post-preview">
    <a href="{{ post.url | prepend: site.baseurl | replace: '//', '/' }}">
      {% if post.title contains "#hashtag" %}
      <br>
      <div class="float-left">
      {% include read-time.html %}
      </div>
      <h2 class="post-title">{{ post.title }}</h2>
      {% if post.subtitle %}
      <h3 class="post-subtitle">{{ post.subtitle }}</h3>
      {% else %}
      <h3 class="post-subtitle">{{ post.excerpt | strip_html | truncatewords: 15 }}</h3>
      {% endif %}
    </a>
    <p class="post-meta float-right">Posted by
      {% if post.author %}
        {{ post.author }}
      {% else %}
        {{ site.author }}
      {% endif %}
      on {{ post.date | date: '%B %d, %Y' }}</p><br>
      {% endif %}
  </article>
```

what I'd like to achieve is to be able to use variable instead of string:

e.g.

{% if post.title contains "{{ content }}" %} - (this way it doesn't work)

instead of

{% if post.title contains "#hashtag" %}

Is there a way to pass variable to post.title contains, or any other way to achieve my goal i.e. filtering results of for loop based on the hashtag in the title ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply write the variable name after `contains`. Example:

```
{% assign a = "Sample text" %}
{% assign b = "text" %}

{% if a contains b %}
    Variable 'a' contains the value of variable 'b'! :)
{% endif %}
```

In your case, `a` will be `post.title` and `b` will be `content`.